# 'Immortal' div element wont get removed

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple function which is executed by an event listener when I click on a certain image.

```
onExit() {
    console.log(this.tag + " should get removed");
    this.tag.remove();
    console.log(this.tag + " should get removed");
}
```

Both messages gets written, and this.tag is not undefined, it most certainly exists.

> **Debug image**

[image]

Comment: tried this.remove()?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `parent` element to remove a `child` element, like this

```
var parent = this.parentElement;
parent.remove(this);
```